# Xonar D1 No Sound

Tags: sound, alsa

Recently my sound card, the Xonar D1, has stopped playing audio through the Front output (on the card itself, not the front of the tower).

It used to work, and I didn't notice which update broke it.

The card is recognized, as I'm still able to use Line-in as an input for my mic.

Here is the [Alsa Info](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=0e3a3a8069d9bb6744c4dbff2f9794d8515561c3).

I've found [this](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84983) bug, could this be related to my problem?

Another strange behavior is that `pavucontrol` (ran over ssh -X forwarding) shows me this: [image: no cards available for configuration]

Although I am able to control the card from alsamixer on the command line. I'm not sure if this is related to my problems with sound output from the card.

How can I get my sound output working again? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This indeed looks like the PulseAudio bug. I guess `aplay -D plughw:0 something.wav` works?

Comment: You said it worked before and as far as I can tell there have been no updates to PulseAudio in 14.04 since January ([changelog](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/pulseaudio)) so I wouldn't suspect that PA is the culprit and the bug related to your problem. Have you checked that the channels have not been muted or set to low volume? Are you sure that the hardware is still functioning properly? Try to check with 14.04.3 live media, another distro like Fedora or Windows if necessary. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems